# generate chain code from binary outer border matrix

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, computer-vision, graph-algorithm

i'm trying to write the following func: 
Given a matrix with all zeros but an objects outer border(equales 1), 
i want to generate a the border chain code.
the hole object is not in the matrix, just its outer border.

*in the example picture - all matrix cells are 0 ,but the blue ones which are 1.[image]

any help is most appreciated!

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, what exactly is "border chain code"?

Comment: is the border guaranteed to be 1 pixel thick ?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is Edge Detection:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection

Comment: by chain code i meant freeman code- which starts from the upper left point of the border ,contains the directions to move through-out the hole border: 0-east, 1-north, 2-west,3-south. you can see the output chain in the example picture.starts from x : 332323..